# Intellij does not recognize import

Tags: java

I am just starting to use Intellij for Java. Something I realized is that it does not even read the line "`import java.io.*;`". The color would be gray. It seems to not import other things either. How do I change this?

The color doesn't matter but when I write a program, it doesn't detect the line: `import java.io.*;` and doesn't understand the IO in something like `num1=IO.getDouble("Enter first number");`.

Comment: Is the project SDK set correctly?

Comment: You probably need to setup JDK. You can read about setting JDK in idea from https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/defining-a-jdk-and-a-mobile-sdk-in-intellij-idea.html

Comment: There is no class `IO` in the `java.io` package. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/package-summary.html

Comment: The setup is correct and based off of https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html#create_project

Answer (score 2):

`IntelliJ` shows imports in **gray** when **they are not used** anywhere in the code of your class.

**IO** is not a class of the package [`java.io`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/package-summary.html) which is the reason why it doesn't know it and your import is in **gray**.

Comment: Is that why it "doesn't understand the IO in something like `num1=IO.getDouble("Enter first number")`;" though?

Comment: If I add something like DecimalFormat three = new DecimalFormat("#,###.000");, then intellij automatically adds import java.text.DecimalFormat; to the top. Then IO is a class of what other package? How come it doesn't automatically adds it to the top?

Comment: it doesn't add it automatically because IO is obviously not part of the dependencies of your project. I personally don't know any class called IO